# Is this using CString with heap or stack? How do I use it with heap memory?

Tags: c++, memory-management, heap-memory, c-strings, stack-memory

I'm using VS2012. I'd rather be allocating memory for CString off of the heap, so given the code below:

1. Is CString csToken allocating memory from the **stack** or **heap**?
2. Do I need to free memory that csToken is using, or will it automatically be freed at the function termination?

   ```
   TCHAR *sAllCodes = (TCHAR *) calloc(50000,sizeof(TCHAR));       // Dynamically use Heap memory to hold all pipe-delimited codes
   TCHAR *sCode = (TCHAR *) calloc(128,sizeof(TCHAR)); // Dynamically use Heap memory to hold a single code
   DWORD i = 0;

   LoadAllCodes(&sAllCodes);       // Custom function

   CString csToken;        // Declare the CString variable
   csToken.Append(sAllCodes);  // Assign the string to the Cstring variable
   vector<CString> vAllCodes;  // Declare the vector variable
   vAllCodes = Split(csToken,L"|");        // Split the CString into a vector array

   while ( i < (DWORD) vAllCodes.size())
       {
       if (vAllCodes[i].StringLength() > 0)        // If there is a string in the vector item
           {
           _stprintf_s(sCode,128,L"%s",vAllCodes[i].GetString());      // Get the vector item and copy it into a string

           // Do work on sCode here...
           }
       i++;
       }

   free(sAllCodes);sAllCodes=NULL;
   free(sCode);sCode=NULL;
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `csToken` variable is an instance of `CString` allocated on the **stack**, so you don't need to do anything to delete it: its *destructor* will do proper string cleanup when the scope of this variable terminates.

However, `CString` *internally* maintains a reference to the actual string, that is allocated on the *heap*.
`CString` actually uses a **["COW"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write)** technique and reference counting, so several `CString` instances can *share* the same string, they can reference to the same string. However, these are `CString` *implementation details*.

The "take away" for a basic usage of `CString` is that if you have `CString str` you don't have to pay attention to `str` cleanup: it will be *automatically* managed by `CString` destructor.

---

Moreover, I'd like to take this occasion to make a few notes on your code, with the spirit of improving it.

**Use `std::vector`**

You have these allocations at the top of your posted code:

> ```
> TCHAR *sAllCodes = (TCHAR *) calloc(50000,sizeof(TCHAR));
> TCHAR *sCode = (TCHAR *) calloc(128,sizeof(TCHAR));
> ```

and then you have the corresponding free calls at the bottom:

> ```
> free(sAllCodes);sAllCodes=NULL;
> free(sCode);sCode=NULL;
> ```

Note however that this code is **not** *exception safe*: in fact, if any code between the `calloc()` and the `free()` calls happens to throw a C++ exception, the memory allocated on the heap for `sAllCodes` and `sCode` will **not** be released.

In a *more modern* and *more practical* C++ style, you could use **`std::vector`** instead of `calloc()` to allocate the memory on the heap, and *automatically* free it, thanks to `std::vector` destructor (just like for `CString`!).

Just substitute the `calloc()` calls with:

```
std::vector<TCHAR> allCodes(50000);
std::vector<TCHAR> code(128);
```

and just delete the `free()` calls! :)
Besides being simpler and shorter, your code becomes also exception-safe; in fact, if a C++ exception is thrown, `vector` destructor is *automatically* called, and the allocated memory is released.

If you want to access `vector` data, you can use its `data()` member function.

If you want to set the initial vector content to all 0s, you can use the `vector v(count, 0)` constructor overload.

**Use C++-style casts**

In your code you have a C-style `(DWORD)` cast. C-style casts are *bad*; consider using **C++-style casts** instead. In your case, you might want a `static_cast<DWORD>(...)`.

**Use `CString::IsEmpty()` to improve readability**

You have an if in your code like this:

> ```
> if (vAllCodes[i].StringLength() > 0)
> ```

`CString` offers a convenient `IsEmpty()` method, that is more readable:

```
if (! vAllCodes[i].IsEmpty()) 
    ....
```

**Notes on `_stprintf_s()` and "magic numbers"**

You use `_stprintf_s()` like this:

> ```
> _stprintf_s(sCode,128,L"%s",vAllCodes[i].GetString());
> ```

But note that if you use the **`TCHAR` model**, for coherence you should use **`_T("%s")`** in the format specifier.
If you want to just use **Unicode** strings and **`L"%s"`** (which I suggest), then use the corresponding Unicode-only **`swprintf_s()`**, and get rid of `TCHAR` and just use **`wchar_t`** instead.

Note also that, instead of using the *"magic number" 128*, you may want to use `sCode.size()` (assuming `sCode` becomes an instance of `std::vector`, as I suggested above). So, if you change the size of the vector, you don't have to update also the "magic number" 128 (with these magic numbers, there are basically bugs waiting to happen :)
The updated code might be something like:

```
swprintf_s(code.data(), code.size(), L"%s", vAllCodes[i].GetString());
```

Comment: Cool! How do I then, with a vector, do an swprintf_s, _tcscpy_s, _tcscat_s?

Comment: Also, doesn't the compiler just substitute _st* functions with sw* anyway, so the net result is not speed loss?

Comment: @JeffR: I already showed that in my example: use `vector::data()` and `vector::size()`. As for your second comment, yes it's just a matter of preprocessor stuff: there's no speed loss.

Comment: I see now! Doing a 'new TCHAR(n)' limits n to 65535. Are there limits for vectors? Or speed-penalties for using vectors?

Comment: @JeffR: I don't understand the limit you wrote. The limit for `std::vector` memory allocations are those of available memory. I think if `vector` fails to allocate its memory, a `std::bad_alloc` exception is thrown. As for speed-penalties, if you use the `vector::operator[]` overload (e.g. `v[i]`), this is as efficient as for raw arrays (there is a small penalty if you use the `vector::at()` method, since it does bounds-checking in both debug and release builds in Visual C++).

Comment: I meant doing 'TCHAR *sAllCodes = new TCHAR(n)'; if n > 65535, this does not compile.

Comment: Is there something in vector to replace _tcslen(sTemp.data())? sTemp.size() is the actual space allocated for the vector. I'm looking to see the data length.

Comment: @JeffR: `new TCHAR(n)` allocates **one** `TCHAR` initialized to `n`. Since `TCHAR` is `wchar_t` in Unicode builds, it's an unsigned 16-bit integer, so you have the maximum value of 65,535 (= 2^16 - 1). If you want to allocate `n` `TCHAR`s using raw `new[]` use `new TCHAR[n]` (note the **square braces** `[` and `]`).

Comment: @JeffR: If you want string operations like `_tcslen()`, consider using a string class instead of `std::vector`. Consider also writing other questions, instead of continuing to comment here.

Answer (score 2):

Anything that is allocated on the stack will be freed once a function goes out of scope. Anything on the heap must be explicitly freed.

`csToken` hasn't been allocated with the `new` keyword, so it is on the stack, rather than the heap.

Finally, I see that you are using C++, and it is very taboo to use `free()` and `malloc()` in C++. You should use the `new` and `delete` keywords.

EDIT:

This line can be rewritten:

```
TCHAR *sAllCodes = (TCHAR *) calloc(50000,sizeof(TCHAR));
```

as:

```
TCHAR *sAllCodes = new TCHAR(5000);
```

This is how to use the new keyword.

Comment: how would I change malloc/free to new/delete? any why is it taboo? Seems to work fine?

Comment: The actual memory used by the ```CString``` class to store the string is allocated on the heap. Once ```csToken``` goes out of scope, the deconstructor is called and you don't need to worry about manually freeing the internal buffer.

Comment: `TCHAR *sAllCodes = new TCHAR[5000]; ... delete[] sAllCodes;`

Comment: evidently, I can only put 65535 (int) max into 'new TCHAR[x]'! Compiler returns "warning C4305: 'initializing' : truncation from 'int' to 'TCHAR'" and "warning C4309: 'initializing' : truncation of constant value"

Answer (score 2):

1. `CString csToken` variable is allocated on the stack, but once some string is assigned to it, it allocates its internal buffers on the heap.
2. You don't need to release any memory occupied by `csToken` explicity, it will be released once `csToken` variable goes out of scope, and its destructor is called.

Comment: 1. So the allocation of memory on the stack for csToken is all replaced by heap memory once a string is assigned to it?

Comment: No. Think about CString as a class containing, lets say, pointer and length (ptr and l). Initially both are 0. Once CString value is assigned, heap memory is allocated, and string is placed there. ptr points to this memory, and l is equal to the string length. ptr and l are still on the stack.

Comment: BTW, the fact that `CString` may allocate its own resources on the heap, is transparent for you - you don't need to do anything with this.

Comment: Ok, I see. Am I doing my CString the most efficient way in this code, or is there a better way? (btw, I'm not using MFC, this is a console app [service] with '#include <atlstr.h>' at the code top so I can use CString)

Comment: I cannot say anything about the whole algorithm, but using local variable `CString csToken;` is absolutely OK in this case. Using `calloc` is a bit unusual in C++, better to use `new`, as already mentioned by Cygwinnian.